# Bad encoded chars in RSS file

Tags: php, encoding, rss

my RSS http://integralsport.com/rss.php?discussions does not work with Netvibes, but work well with others RSS reader (like Google one).

With the help of W3 validator, I find severals specials chars 
http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fintegralsport.com%2Frss.php%3Fdiscussions

How can I encode them correctly? I try severals way (\x90 notation, direct str_replace) but none of them work.

Comment: How are you generating the xml in php?

Comment: Yes, the XML/RSS is generated by a PHP script, but data came from Mysql database, and the users of my forum type in such chars.

Answer (score 0):

you may try converting your document to UTF-8 and running

```
htmlentities($description, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

upon outputting the description of the item (same goes for title)

Comment: This doesn't fix the underlying problem.

Comment: Nothing different with UTF-8 encoding of strings

Comment: the main thing here is htmlentities.. if you will have "é" or other stuff, it may report errors.. see this link http://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/warning/BadCharacters.html and read carefully where it states "This error is commonly seen when an encoding like iso-8859-1 is declared when what actually is desired is windows-1252"

Answer (score -2):

Wrap the text in a CDATA tag:

```
<![CDATA[ Héllo world ]]>
```

Comment: I doubt this is it. The validator seems to be complaining about actual invalid characters in that character set

Comment: It does not help since RSS reader ignore the whole CDATA blocs